# Removing first N characters from a very large file

Tags: large-files, fileparsing

I have a rather big `csv` file, which contains a single row, and on the last "column", there is a HUGE `json` string.

I already found a solution, to parse this JSON string programatically, but my problem is, that I would first need a solution to GET only this JSON string, without loading the whole file in the memory of course (the file is around 50GB).

Is there any program (preferably for linux), which for example would let me open the first 2-3 mb of the file for editing, so I can delete the unneccessary text from the beginning of the file?

Comment: So you want the last column on the first (and only) line in the file?

Comment: Yes, but without putting the whole file into the memory, or even that last column, which I need for that matter. Basically, 99% of the file is the last column that I need, which is too big, to fit in memory at once.

Comment: If you can figure out the start and end positions of the json you should be able read just that.